# asyncpg.exceptions.AmbiguousParameterError: could not determine data type of parameter

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, fastapi

Am creating an endpoint to search in FastAPI, but am facing this error :

```
asyncpg.exceptions.AmbiguousParameterError: could not determine data type of parameter $2
```

I have defined my sql query in queries.py :

```
GET_LOG_QUERY = """
SELECT *
FROM activities
WHERE entity = :entity
AND types_id = :types_id
AND (
    :search IS NULL OR :search = '' 
    OR full_name ILIKE :search
    OR email ILIKE :search
)
```

"""

and here's the repository, :

```
class LogActivitiesRepository(BaseRepository):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super().__init__(db=db)

    async def get_activities(self, types_id: str, entity: str, search: Optional[str] = None) -> List[LogActivityModel]:
        search_pattern = f"%{search}%" if search else "%"
        records = await self.db.fetch_all(
            query=GET_LOG_QUERY,
            values={
                "entity": entity_name,
                "types_id": types_id,
                "search": search_pattern
            }
        )
        if not records:
            return []
        return [LogActivityModel(**record._mapping) for record in records]
```

If I don't consider the search field it works very well in the query set, like the queryset below :

GET_LOG_QUERY = """
SELECT *
FROM user_activities
WHERE entity_name = :entity_name
AND tenant_id = :tenant_id;
"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't know the type of the value of `:search` as it isn't defined in any of the tables in the query:

```
test# select $1 is null \bind 'x' \g
ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

You might be able to get away with casting `:search` where it is being used on the right hand side of a comparison:

```py
GET_LOG_QUERY = """
SELECT *
FROM activities
WHERE entity = :entity
AND types_id = :types_id
AND (
    :search::varchar IS NULL OR :search::varchar = '' 
    OR full_name ILIKE :search
    OR email ILIKE :search
)
"""
```

However it's probably a better idea to evaluate the boolean expression in the Python layer and replace `:search IS NULL OR :search = ''` with the result.

```py
GET_LOG_QUERY = """
SELECT *
FROM activities
WHERE entity = :entity
AND types_id = :types_id
AND (
    :no_pattern 
    OR full_name ILIKE :search
    OR email ILIKE :search
)
"""

...

        no_pattern = not bool(search_pattern)
        records = await self.db.fetch_all(
            query=GET_LOG_QUERY,
            values={
                "entity": entity_name,
                "types_id": types_id,
                "search": search_pattern,
                "no_pattern": no_pattern,
            }
        )
```